# How to integrate C++ application into PHP website?

Tags: php, c++, webserver, integration

I have a c++ application that processes a sentence and responds back to the respective user. I have a website using php that I would like to post data to this application and receive this response. Ideally, the C++ would run on the webserver and not have to be fully loaded each time it is used, but i haven't been able to get a simple 'hello world' (with cgi or c++) to work on the webserver.

What would be the easiest way to integrate a c++ application into a website? Should this work with any webhost?

Comment: There must be a way to extend php since most scripting languages (e.g. Python) allow you to do this.  Usually this is done with C.  You can do this in C++ by creating a wrapper of C function entry points into you C++ application/library.  Search "extending php".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Integrate them you can take two approaches.

1) Integrate C++ as a function into PHP with http://www.php-cpp.com 
You can create a function, say my_complex_function, that when called in PHP, will execute a C++ code. You can read the site's documentation for information about it.

2) Keep them separate and communicate through HTTP/Pipes/Sockets/Other
You could build a C++ daemon that opens up some kind of communication interface like a Socket, then with PHP you open a socket to it, send the information through the socket, and receive the answer there too.
You can find socket examples for PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: Thanks. I'll proabably end up doing #2 since that is what I'm familiar with. I'll have to make the PHP on my external webserver connect-to/run the c++ on my local computer.

Comment: Which approach is less likely to have security problems?